# Usar resolução de tela diferente de acordo com o monitor

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, resolução-de-tela

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em 1920x1080, porém os PCs que vão rodar são 1280x720 e 1366 x 768.

Quando executo no meu fica exatamente como quero, mas ao rodar neste resoluções, fica quebrado bastante coisa. Tem como ajustar isso? Ou tenho que fazer um código para cada resolução diferente?

Comment: Seja mais especifico. É preferível que poste o código onde isso acontece, é um componente que não fica no lugar certo? De uma passada pelo [tour] para entender melhor como funciona o site. E veja como escrever um [mcve]

Comment: nao tem codigo, eu so simplesmente deixo um botão na propriedade SIZE 200x50, e em outras resoluções ele saiu por exemplo 260x60.
mas o painel que contem eles, tem tamanho máximo de 200x540, nisso os últimos botões ficam foram da visualização

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 3):

Tem, faça tudo de novo considerando que vai rodar em uma máquina que não é a sua e nunca mais acredite no

[image: funciona na minha máquina]

um dos memes mais famosos da programação.

- Ou você refaz todas as telas pensando no mínimo denominador comum, no caso 1280x720 (mas pode aparecer inferiores)
- ou faz vários *layouts* para cada resolução
- ou usa um sistema de *layout* do Windows Forms (veja abaixo)
- ou mude para o WPF que é o mais adequado para estes casos porque pode tanto apresentar mais informações na tela como pode apresentar a mesma informação maior ou menor se tiver mais ou menos espaço na tela (é possível simular isto no WinForms, mas é bem complicado).

O mais comum é usar um [`FlowLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), mas pode ser que o [`TableLayoutPanel Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) te sirva bem. Você pode ver outras classes painéis que ajudam no *layout*, você pode ver algumas delas derivadas da classe [`Panel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.panel?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), e é possível você criar o seu painel, mas dá trabalho. Obviamente tem que saber usar adequadamente para que o *layout* seja flexível de forma adequada.

Outra forma comum é utilização de [`Control.Anchor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que estabelece de onde um controle deve começar ser colocado. Se souber ancorar tudo pode obter um resultado interessante. Pode combinar as duas.

Mas teste em várias resoluções, nem sempre fica bom em alguns casos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: FlowLayoutPanel tambem trabalha na horizontal?
porque ja uso ele num menu DropDown , mas na vertical

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.flowdirection?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 2):

Windows Forms tem certas limitações para criar formulários responsível.

Nesses casos de resolução eu sempre construo os formulários na menor resolução que o sistema irá rodar e utilizo as âncoras e painéis, por exemplo, para que possa manter o formulário mais ajustável possível.

Se sua necessidade é um formulário que aceite o máximo de recursos de resolução, sugiro que faça em WPF.

Abraços

Comment: ANCORA!!!! era isso que tava procurando!! vlw
esqueci que existia esta opção!